# pinchable webview

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4, webview

I have a webview, which show a link to a specific website, but the display is fixed, it feels like browsing the web from old style mobile, n not iphone.
Is there a way to make a webview pinchable? Since the webview in my apps is not pinchable, which mean I can't zoom it in or out. 
Any help is appreciated. 
Thanx in advance.

Comment: did you set it up in code or IB?

Comment: I set it up in IB, but if it can only be done in code, you could show me the way as well.. Thanx..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that scale pages to fit is checked in IB, and that multi-touch & user interaction are enabled.

Answer (score 0):

That worked for me:

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds.frame];
webView.scalesPageToFit=TRUE;
```

Comment: Adding code formatting improves the readability of your answer.

Comment: And also, don't add signatures.